# Why am I getting strange results with sed in eshell?

Tags: regex, character-encoding, sed, eshell

I was having trouble piping the results of a 'find' to sed. I simplified it to the simplest thing I could break, and I got this:

```
echo 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | sed 's/[:digit:]*/X/g'
```

I expected to get:

```
Xabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

The output I get from this is:

```
X1X2X3X4X5X6X7X8X9X0XaXbXcXeXfXhXjXkXlXmXnXoXpXqXrXsXuXvXwXxXyXzX
```

which is not what I was expecting. If I change my regex to:

```
echo 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | sed 's/[0-9]*/X/g'
```

I get:

```
XaXbXcXdXeXfXgXhXiXjXkXlXmXnXoXpXqXrXsXtXuXvXwXxXyXzX
```

which is closer to what I expected. I just realized I don't have this problem in a standard terminal, only in aquamacs eshell... I assume it must be a character encoding issue? Maybe unicode related? How do I determine this for sure, and how do I fix this problem?

Comment: What do you expect exactly instead of your second example `XaXbXcXdXeXf...` ? I also use Aquamacs, and get the same output whether in Eshell or Terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the reg-exp char '*' means 'match **zero** or more of the previous char' ( char class in this case)

And as @SamHoice noted, you need '[[:digit:]]'.

So you can either reduced all digits in a row 1 X

```
echo 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | sed 's/[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*/X/g'
Xabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Or substitute X for all digits

```
echo 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | sed 's/[[:digit:]]/X/g'
XXXXXXXXXXabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

If neither of these work, please edit your question to include what you need as your output.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I added what I expected to get.

Comment: does this not work in your eshell? Arg. didn't notice that you answered your own question. Does part 2 help? .Good luck.

Comment: Ok. I understand now. I'm not sure why it didn't seem to be working the same in term and eshell earlier. Because I left out the first [[:digit:]] I never got all of the #s substituted to one X without all the 0 Xs between the letters.

Comment: With cutting and pasting into a term you can sometime wind up with spaces, tabs, other invisible chars that throw off the sensitive nature of sed reg-ex ;-). That's my best guess. If you still have the failing commands in a history buffer, maybe `echo ... | od -m x-ansi` can help you debug it. Thanks for accepting and upvote! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for number one is that the character class [:digit:] itself needs to be enclosed in [], so it should be [[:digit:]].

Still working on the second part.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | sed 's/[0-9]\+\(.*\)/X\1/g'
```

[0-9]+ match the 1234567890

\1 is the .* any letter, except the [:digit:]